# Java ORM without Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, dynamic, orm, mapping

Working with Hibernate, I noticed that all of the Java objects going into persistence are defined in a mapping file. Is there a way to only depend on the annotations instead of a separate .xml for this? At the time of creation, we do not know what the object that is to be persisted contains. We know it is primitive data types, Strings, ints, floats/doubles, but we do not know how many of each field the object may contain until the same time it needs to have a table created for it to be entered into the db.

Note that Hibernate is just the first ORM solution that I've looked at. I am not tied to it if there is another ORM solution that solves this problem.

Comment: Do you realize the contradiction of your question? ORM (Object-Relational **Mapping**) *without* **Mapping**???

Comment: Ha! No I did not realize that. I guess I'm not asking for not mapping, but for the mapping to happen automatically without having to be defined in a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your use case, you can use [Dozer](https://howtodoinjava.com/automation/dozer-bean-mapping-examples/) mapping for managing beans without having explicit definitions of class files and this can ben loaded at runtime using spring annotatons dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into JDX ORM for Java. The mapping is defined declaratively in a text file but just a minimal specification is needed for each class - its name and the names of the primary key attributes. Other attributes are automatically picked up by JDX. So you may continue to modify your class without making any further changes to its mapping specification. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDX ORM.